# gauss newton algorithm and matricial product

Tags: python, newtons-method

I'm trying to make an gauss-newton algorithm on python, and I have an error that I don't understand:

```
np.dot(-Jr(x0,n,t).T,r(x0,t,a,n))
ValueError: shapes (2,7) and (1,7) not aligned: 7 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)`
```

Not sure why my matricial product doesn't work ...
Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
import math

#on défini ici les residus
def r(x,t,a,n):
   r = np.ones((1,n))
   r[0,:] = a[0] - x0[0]*np.exp(-x0[1]*t) 
   return(np.array(r))

#definition du jacobien
def Jr(x,n,t):
   Jr = np.ones((n,2))
   Jr[:,1] = t*x0[0]*np.exp(-x[1]*t)
   Jr[:,0] = -np.exp(-x[1]*t)
   return(Jr)

def f(x,n):
   z = 0
   t = 0
   z = (r(x0,t,a,n))**2
   for i in range (n):
       t = t + z[0][i]
   h = math.sqrt(t)
   return(h)

#initialisation des variables    
t = np.array([500,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6300],dtype=float)
a = np.array([14.5,13.5,12.0,10.8,9.9,8.9,8.0],dtype=float).T
x0 = np.array([10,0.0001])
n = np.size(t)
R = (x0,t,a,n)
X = Jr(x0,n,t)
e = 0.00001
k = 0
x = x0
np.dot(-Jr(x0,n,t).T,r(x0,t,a,n))
#while (1/2)*(f(x,n))**2 > e*(1/2)*(f(x0,n))**2:
    #s = linalg.solve(np.dot(Jr(x,n,t).T,Jr(x,n,t)),np.dot(-          Jr(x,n,t).T,r(x,t,a,n)))
#x = x + s.T
#k = k + 1
#print(x)
#print(k)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
np.dot(-Jr(x0,n,t).T, r(x0,t,a,n).T)
```

this should fix the dimension problem and will result in a matrix with the shape (2,1).